# List sibling pages by taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to list sibling pages of the current page by taxonomy. The following lists all sibling pages of the current page but how do I query by taxonomy term?

```
if($post->post_parent): 
        $children = 
          wp_list_pages('depth=1&title_li=&child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&echo=0'); 
endif; 

if ($children) { 
  // do something 
  $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
  echo $parent_title;
}
```

Comment: It would greatly help if you added an input set and your desired output. This will help myself (and probably others) to understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass `taxonomy` parameter to [wp_list_pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) function. To accomplish your requirement, you can use [wp_get_post_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) to get post taxonomies and use `[get_posts][2]` function to retrieve posts belongs to the category.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have the term you want in another part of your code, you can try this:

```
$siblingPages = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'tag' => $current_tag,
    'post_parent' => $post->post_parent,
    'post__not_in' => $post->ID 
));
```

- 'tag' is the taxonomy you want
- $current_tag is the term you are looking for.
- 'post__not_in' will exclude the current page from the query.